# How do you enable anonymous write access to SQS queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I would like to be able to post messages to my queue without using an aws key.

Comment: This my be helpful: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=311930

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer is yes, you totally can, and its totally easy. Just select the queue and edit the permissions on the bottom of the page. There is an option for "Everybody (*)".

I tested with curl: curl -d "Action=SendMessage&Version=2011-10-01&MessageBody=barf"

Thanks Jarmod.