# How to allow anonymous access for SendMessage to Amazon SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

The AWS SQS docs states that anonymous access is supported: [https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#:~:text=Q%3A%20Does%20Amazon%20SQS%20support%20anonymous%20access%3F](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/#:%7E:text=Q%3A%20Does%20Amazon%20SQS%20support%20anonymous%20access%3F)

It also provides an example policy that grants a permission to all users: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html#:~:text=Example%205%3A%20Grant%20a%20permission%20to%20all%20users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-basic-examples-of-sqs-policies.html#:%7E:text=Example%205%3A%20Grant%20a%20permission%20to%20all%20users)

I've tried to create an SQS queue with the following access policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, an anonymous client (using a cURL request) gets the following error when trying to execute SendMessage:
`Access to the resource The specified queue does not exist or you do not have access to it. is denied.`

A previous solution ([How do you enable anonymous write access to SQS queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632850/how-do-you-enable-anonymous-write-access-to-sqs-queue)) doesn't seem to work anymore.

Is anonymous access to SQS no longer supported by AWS?

Comment: Maybe, its not supported because its a terrible idea and huge security issue. You should front the SQS with an API gateway if you want to expose it to the world.

Comment: I have tried variations on the Access Policy and could not find one that worked with `aws sqs send-message ... --no-sign-request` So, it is indeed a mystery! You might want to try asking at: https://repost.aws/

Answer (score 0):

Allowing anonymous access to your SQS is not really a good thing to do. In your policy, you didn't allow anonymous access, but access to any AWS authenticated user. To allow anonymous, you should change the `Principal` part of the policy to:

`"Principal": "*",`